# Test the consistency of the mult-replicate outcomes for each subject in R

Tags: r

Suppose I have an outcome such like:

```
df<-data.frame(id=rep(letters[1:4], each=4), stringsAsFactors=FALSE,
               test=c(rep(FALSE, 4), rep(c(FALSE, TRUE), 4), rep(TRUE, 4)))
   id  test
1   a FALSE
2   a FALSE
3   a FALSE
4   a FALSE
5   b FALSE
6   b  TRUE
7   b FALSE
8   b  TRUE
9   c FALSE
10  c  TRUE
11  c FALSE
12  c  TRUE
13  d  TRUE
14  d  TRUE
15  d  TRUE
16  d  TRUE
```

What I wanted to see is whether the test results were consistent across each subject. Such that:

```
   id  consist
1   a TRUE
2   b FALSE
3   c FALSE
4   d TRUE
```

What is an easy way to realize this in R?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a method using `aggregate`:

```
aggregate(test ~ id, data=df, FUN=function(x) min(x) == max(x))
  id  test
1  a  TRUE
2  b FALSE
3  c FALSE
4  d  TRUE
```

For each, id, the function checks whether the min of the test results equal the maximum of the results.

A second method is to check if there are any differences in the values using `diff`:

```
aggregate(test ~ id, data=df, FUN=function(x) max(abs(diff(x))) == 0)
  id  test
1  a  TRUE
2  b FALSE
3  c FALSE
4  d  TRUE
```

Here, taking the maximum of the absolute value to get the magnitude of the differences.

Answer (score 2):

Could also check if either `TRUE` or `FALSE` isn't present at all by group using `table` and `rowSums` combination

```
rowSums(table(df) == 0)
# a b c d 
# 1 0 0 1
```

Or closer to your desired output

```
data.frame(test = rowSums(table(df) == 0) == 1)
#    test
# a  TRUE
# b FALSE
# c FALSE
# d  TRUE
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach using `dplyr` package

```
df %>%group_by(id) %>% summarise(consist=ifelse(var(test)==0,TRUE,FALSE))
```

---

Thanks to @David Arenburg's comment, We can simplify above using base R by doing this

```
data.frame(test=with(df, tapply(test, id, var)) == 0)
```

Comment: You could probably simplify this using base R, by something like `with(df, tapply(test, id, var)) == 0`

Comment: Cause you came up with the `var` part

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .(consist= all(test)| all(!test)) , by = id]
#   id consist
#1:  a  TRUE
#2:  b FALSE
#3:  c FALSE
#4:  d  TRUE
```

---

Or use `uniqueN`

```
setDT(df)[,.(consist = uniqueN(test)==1) , by = id]
```